# DSpace: Passing the authority via OAI

Tags: dspace

I wonder if via the OAI the authority of a metadata can also be passed ?

Metadata value have a text_Value and an authority. Can this authority be passed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can expose the authority key via OAI (that's assuming you're on XOAI -- this became standard in DSpace 3). Here is an example from a custom metadata format, `org_theses`, exposing the text value (`org_theses:name`) and the authority key (`org_theses:id`) for all `dc.contributor.advisor` entries:

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='dc']/doc:element[@name='contributor']/doc:element[@name='advisor']/doc:element">
  <org_theses:supervisor>
    <org_theses:name>
      <xsl:value-of select="doc:field[@name='value']" />
    </org_theses:name>
    <org_theses:id>
      <xsl:value-of select="doc:field[@name='authority']" />
    </org_theses:id>
  </org_theses:supervisor>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Place this in the appropriate file in `[dspace]/config/crosswalks/oai/metadataFormats`.

The XSL files in the `metadataFormats` directory operate on the XOAI representation of the item, which you can look at if you have that metadata format enabled in `xoai.xml`. In theory you'd get there via eg http://demo.dspace.org/oai/request?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=xoai but it looks like the DSpace demo server currently doesn't have any OAI records available.